# cedar fireplace mantel

Tags: wood, live-edge

I am making a mantel from a piece of red cedar which has been cut flat on the bottom and top.  I have scraped and removed the loose bark from the sides.  I like the look of leaving some layers of of brown bark to give a brown color instead on removing all bark (white).  Will those strips loosen w/ time?

Comment: It's unfortunately impossible to say for sure. If they are currently well attached you could be lucky, but small areas of peeling or lifting of edges are always a possibility in the future. You could be lucky or not, and it's one reason bark is usually removed entirely from formal woodworking projects (different standard for rustic stuff, and outdoor projects).

Comment: I have had luck (but not always) using an oil based wipe on poly. Soak the bark thoroughly.

Comment: @MonteGlover that may as well be an answer, since you have tried it with some success, and have a technique you can pass on.

Comment: You can soak it with super _thin_ CA glue - this will strengthen it and it won't break off - but it may be hard to apply finish later (depending on finish of course). You can try it on a piece of scrap wood.

Comment: @JanSpurny have you tried this? If so, why not provide an Answer?

Comment: @jdv - because it's just an idea, I'm not 100% sure if it's the right thing for Joyce's project..

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because any Answer would be guesswork.

Comment: @Graphus, I read this as "how can I maintain/preserve this live-edge mantel?" rather than "will this mantel fall apart". I gave it the live-edge tag, but it could be tweaked to be this answerable question. That being said, closing because the OP lost interest is also valid.

Comment: @jdv, the main query seems to be *"Will those [bark] strips loosen w/ time?"* Which of course nobody can know. Plus, even when the Question was new as far as we can tell the OP never returned to read any of the responses!

Comment: Agreed in part, though the implied question is _really_ "how can I stop live-edge mantle from falling apart". It's just the last sentence that makes the only SE mistake. If I edit it to "How can I maintain this look that I like?" (which is clearly the implied, or follow-up, question here) it would be answerable without a doubt. The fact that it has been abandoned (well, a photo would have been nice, too) is a problem. But the question itself is salvageable if anyone has interest in either the Q or the A.

Comment: That _all_ being said, we do have a fair amount of "live-edge" Q&A, but none of them really cover simple queries of how to preserve such construction. This one has the added wrinkle of also referring to mantel finishing, which may have its own considerations. I just see this as a potential good Q&A for the site, mostly because it is a relevant subject that has not been covered before here.